# Reporting Services: Cannot connect to Oracle using Integrated Security

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, integrated-security

**Context**

I have an Oracle 11g database instance and a SQL Server 2012 instance installed on 2 different servers in the same domain. The Oracle database is configured to accept connection with Integrated Security (ie. Active Directory authentication). SQL Server has the Reporting Services feature installed and configured. Reporting Services will connect to Oracle database using the Oracle .NET data provider *from Microsoft*.

**Issue**

When creating a data connection to the database in Visual Studio I have no problem to connect to the Oracle database using Integrated Security. I configured the connection with this connection string:

```
Data Source=INSTANCE_NAME;Integrated Security=True;Unicode=True
```

But whenever I try to create a data source in Reporting Services from the SSRS website, from Report Builder or from BIDS, I am getting a login error:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I tried copying the exact same connection string but the result is always the same. It looks like Reporting Services is ignoring the `Integrated Security=True` option for an unknown reason.

**Notes**

The same issue occurs with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Oracle .NET data provider from Oracle cannot be used with Reporting Services.

Comment: U tried add the domain to your username with domain\username and/or username@domain ?

Comment: I do not want to provide any username/password manually but provide automatically my current Windows user, that is the whole point of Integrated Security.

Comment: Did you try `Integrated Security=yes` ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade: I just tried with `Yes` instead of `True` and I get the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean `Integrated Security` with oracle, as far as I know since 11g there is no really OS authentication, instead there is the `Secure External Password Store` so how is your environment configured ? can you connect like that from sql*plus (WO user/password)?

Comment: Effectively we use AD as the `Secure External Password Store`. So for each AD user that needs access to DB we create an Oracle user with a login in the form $DOMAIN\USERNAME and with an external password. This is how we enable `Integrated Security`. But this does work with no issue in any tool, including Visual Studio. It only fails with SSRS...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but is it possible that you have more then one `oracle client` on your machine and the SSRS is using a different instance than the Visual studio ? another thing, did you try to put empty user/passwd ? ie `User Id=/;Password=;`

Comment: I have two Oracle clients installed on the server, each for 32 and 64 bits. About the connection string, the problem is that we have to use the Microsoft Oracle provider which does not have notion of `User Id`, does not allow blank password, but allows `Integrated Security` to emulate the `User Id=/;Password=;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem. When you need to pass credentials that needs to be transmitted to another server (Client -> SSRS -> DB), the default authentication system (NTLM) won't be enough because it can't perform double hop authentication. You need to give the rights to the report server to delegate authentication through Kerberos on the DC. So that means that you also have to enable RSWindowsNegotiate as the default authentication system for your report server and that you define SPNs for SSRS and its service account.

More details can be found here: https://serverfault.com/q/378096/85935